# ListView Item's position repeated

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a dynamic `listview` using fragment in which item's position are repeating after 6th index(Note- items are not repeating).

I have to change quantity of item on button click, but when I try to click and change quantity at index 0 it also changes the 7th index quantity.

Please help me out
Thanx in advance.

```
    public class MenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {

    private Activity activity;

    public String[] ItemsList = new String[1000];
    public String[] ItemsRelPrice;

    ArrayList<String> foodItemTitle = new ArrayList<>();

    private static String currentTitle;

    private String selection;
    private String ttl;


    public MenuListAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, List<DataModel> dataModelList) {
        super(activity, resource, dataModelList);

        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public DataModel getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_item_list, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

            final ImageButton addBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_add);
            final ImageButton removeBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_remove);

            final TextView qty = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
            final TextView priceTtl = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cost);
            final TextView foodItem = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            final TextView foodPrice = convertView.findViewById(R.id.per_item_cost);

            addBtn.setTag(position);
            addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Log.v("btn tag", String.valueOf(addBtn.getTag()));
                    Log.v("qty tag", String.valueOf(qty.getTag()));
                    Log.v("Price tag", String.valueOf(priceTtl.getTag()));

                    int curntQty = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) + 1;
                    int costPerItem = Integer.valueOf(foodPrice.getText().toString());

                    if (qty.getTag() == addBtn.getTag())
                        qty.setText(String.valueOf(curntQty));

                    if (priceTtl.getTag() == addBtn.getTag())
                        priceTtl.setText(String.valueOf(costPerItem * curntQty));

                    new MenuPage().addItem(costPerItem);

                }
            });

            removeBtn.setTag(position);
            removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (qty.getText().toString() != "0") {

                        int qtyTtl = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) - 1;
                        qty.setText(String.valueOf(qtyTtl));

                        int costPerItem = Integer.valueOf(foodPrice.getText().toString());
                        int curPrice = Integer.valueOf(priceTtl.getText().toString());

                        priceTtl.setText(String.valueOf(curPrice - costPerItem));

                        new MenuPage().removeItem(costPerItem);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add Item First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);

        holder.foodItem.setTag(position);
        holder.foodItem.setText(dataModel.getItemTitleFinal());

        holder.foodPrice.setTag(position);
        holder.foodPrice.setText(dataModel.getItemPriceFinal());

        holder.foodType.setTag(position);
        holder.foodType.setImageResource(dataModel.getItemImgFinal());

        holder.addBtn.setTag(position);
        holder.removeBtn.setTag(position);
        holder.qty.setTag(position);
        holder.priceCurnt.setTag(position);

        return convertView;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {

        private TextView foodItem;
        private TextView foodPrice;
        private ImageView foodType;
        private ImageButton addBtn;
        private ImageButton removeBtn;
        private TextView qty;
        private TextView priceCurnt;


        public ViewHolder(View v) {

            foodItem = v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            foodPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.per_item_cost);
            foodType = v.findViewById(R.id.fdTypeImg);
            addBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.img_add);
            removeBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.img_remove);
            qty = v.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
            priceCurnt = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_cost);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show code please.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the code.

Comment: you have to mention someone if it's not their question or answer,

Comment: @MohamedEmbaby help me out bro

Comment: Wait, I'm coming up with an answer

Comment: It is due to the view is recycled. I see your qty textview value is not depend on the data, just have been set when you click addBtn button. As you said that when you change quantity(via click addBtn) at index 0. At the 7th index, the view(at index 0) is recycled. But the different is the addBtn at the 7th index have not clicked yet so the qty textview use the previous value(at the 0 index). You should make qty textview depend on your data or temparory quantity list to avoid this issue

Comment: @TruongGiangDam  how can I make qty textview dependent on data? what u actually said?

Comment: store the quantity in DataModel as a field. In getView you call holder.qty.setText(dataModel.getQuantity()); Now whenever addBtn/removeBtn you update quantity directly into the model. Then call notifyDataSetChanged() to update the UI. If you think this way maybe change your model structure and you don't wanna it, create the int array as a temporary quantity list. Use this temporary to save the quantity and update it every times the quantity change.

Comment: @TruongGiangDam I tried to make qty dynamic but its not working, when I click on addBtn qty increases but when I scroll down and up it reset to initialize value.

Comment: tell me  did you store the quantity in DataModel or use temporary quantity list?. I will write the answer below for you

Comment: @TruongGiangDam I stored the quantity in datamodel

Comment: look at my answer, let me know if it work or not. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I modified your adapter class. You need to have `dataModelList` which will act as source to inflate the view holders. Now, you need to supply the list through the constructor and make small modifications at places where I might have missed. Let me know if modifications are needed.

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {

private Activity activity;

public String[] ItemsList = new String[1000];
public String[] ItemsRelPrice;

ArrayList<String> foodItemTitle = new ArrayList<>();

private static String currentTitle;

private String selection;
private String ttl;

//List of DataModel objects to inflate into view holders
private List<DataModel> dataModelList;


public MenuListAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, List<DataModel> dataModelList) {
    super(activity, resource, dataModelList);
    this.activity = activity;
    //set the list in constructor
    this.dataModelList = dataModelList;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public DataModel getItem(int position) {
    return dataModelList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataModelList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return dataModelList.get(position).getId();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

     ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_item_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //findViewById codes removed because they are unnecessary
    //Copy to final object so that it can be used inside inner classes
    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);

    finalHolder.foodItem.setTag(position);
    finalHolder.foodItem.setText(dataModel.getItemTitleFinal());

    finalHolder.foodPrice.setTag(position);
    finalHolder.foodPrice.setText(dataModel.getItemPriceFinal());

    finalHolder.foodType.setTag(position);
    finalHolder.foodType.setImageResource(dataModel.getItemImgFinal());

    finalHolder.addBtn.setTag(position);
    finalHolder.removeBtn.setTag(position);

    finalHolder.qty.setTag(position);
    finalHolder.priceCurnt.setTag(position);

    finalHolder.addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.v("btn tag", String.valueOf(finalHolder.addBtn.getTag()));
            Log.v("qty tag", String.valueOf(finalHolder.qty.getTag()));
            Log.v("Price tag", String.valueOf(finalHolder.priceCurnt.getTag()));

            int curntQty = Integer.parseInt(finalHolder.qty.getText().toString()) + 1;
            int costPerItem = Integer.valueOf(finalHolder.foodPrice.getText().toString());

            if (finalHolder.qty.getTag() == finalHolder.addBtn.getTag())
                finalHolder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(curntQty));

            if (finalHolder.priceCurnt.getTag() == finalHolder.addBtn.getTag())
                finalHolder.priceCurnt.setText(String.valueOf(costPerItem * curntQty));

            new MenuPage().addItem(costPerItem);

        }
    });

    finalHolder.removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (finalHolder.qty.getText().toString() != "0") {

                int qtyTtl = Integer.parseInt(finalHolder.qty.getText().toString()) - 1;
                finalHolder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(qtyTtl));

                int costPerItem = Integer.valueOf(finalHolder.foodPrice.getText().toString());
                int curPrice = Integer.valueOf(finalHolder.priceCurnt.getText().toString());

                finalHolder.priceCurnt.setText(String.valueOf(curPrice - costPerItem));

                new MenuPage().removeItem(costPerItem);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add Item First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}


private static class ViewHolder {

    private TextView foodItem;
    private TextView foodPrice;
    private ImageView foodType;
    private ImageButton addBtn;
    private ImageButton removeBtn;
    private TextView qty;
    private TextView priceCurnt;


    public ViewHolder(View v) {

        foodItem = v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        foodPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.per_item_cost);
        foodType = v.findViewById(R.id.fdTypeImg);
        addBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.img_add);
        removeBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.img_remove);
        qty = v.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
        priceCurnt = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_cost);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is getId() used in getItemId()

Comment: It should be the getter for the id of `DataModel` object you are using. If you don't have an `id` field for your class `DataModel`, you can just keep the super class call as before.

Answer (score 0):

Change following code:

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_item_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

        final ImageButton addBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_add);
        final ImageButton removeBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_remove);

        final TextView qty = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
        final TextView priceTtl = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cost);
        final TextView foodItem = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        final TextView foodPrice = convertView.findViewById(R.id.per_item_cost);

        addBtn.setTag(position);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Log.v("btn tag", String.valueOf(addBtn.getTag()));
                Log.v("qty tag", String.valueOf(qty.getTag()));
                Log.v("Price tag", String.valueOf(priceTtl.getTag()));

                int curntQty = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) + 1;
                int costPerItem = Integer.valueOf(foodPrice.getText().toString());

                if (qty.getTag() == addBtn.getTag())
                    qty.setText(String.valueOf(curntQty));

                if (priceTtl.getTag() == addBtn.getTag())
                    priceTtl.setText(String.valueOf(costPerItem * curntQty));

                new MenuPage().addItem(costPerItem);

            }
        });

        removeBtn.setTag(position);
        removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (qty.getText().toString() != "0") {

                    int qtyTtl = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) - 1;
                    qty.setText(String.valueOf(qtyTtl));

                    int costPerItem = Integer.valueOf(foodPrice.getText().toString());
                    int curPrice = Integer.valueOf(priceTtl.getText().toString());

                    priceTtl.setText(String.valueOf(curPrice - costPerItem));

                    new MenuPage().removeItem(costPerItem);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add Item First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);

    holder.foodItem.setTag(position);
    holder.foodItem.setText(dataModel.getItemTitleFinal());

    holder.foodPrice.setTag(position);
    holder.foodPrice.setText(dataModel.getItemPriceFinal());

    holder.foodType.setTag(position);
    holder.foodType.setImageResource(dataModel.getItemImgFinal());

    holder.addBtn.setTag(position);
    holder.removeBtn.setTag(position);
    holder.qty.setTag(position);
    holder.priceCurnt.setTag(position);

    return convertView;
}


private static class ViewHolder {

    private TextView foodItem;
    private TextView foodPrice;
    private ImageView foodType;
    private ImageButton addBtn;
    private ImageButton removeBtn;
    private TextView qty;
    private TextView priceCurnt;


    public ViewHolder(View v) {

        foodItem = v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        foodPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.per_item_cost);
        foodType = v.findViewById(R.id.fdTypeImg);
        addBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.img_add);
        removeBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.img_remove);
        qty = v.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
        priceCurnt = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_cost);
    }
}
```

To:

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_stock, parent, false);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_item_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

        final ImageButton addBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_add);
        final ImageButton removeBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_remove);

        final TextView qty = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
        final TextView priceTtl = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cost);
        final TextView foodItem = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        final TextView foodPrice = convertView.findViewById(R.id.per_item_cost);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);

    holder.foodItem.setTag(position);
    holder.foodItem.setText(dataModel.getItemTitleFinal());

    holder.foodPrice.setTag(position);
    holder.foodPrice.setText(dataModel.getItemPriceFinal());

    holder.foodType.setTag(position);
    holder.foodType.setImageResource(dataModel.getItemImgFinal());

    holder.addBtn.setTag(position);
    holder.removeBtn.setTag(position);
    holder.qty.setTag(position);
    holder.priceCurnt.setTag(position);


    holder.addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Log.v("btn tag", String.valueOf(addBtn.getTag()));
                Log.v("qty tag", String.valueOf(qty.getTag()));
                Log.v("Price tag", String.valueOf(priceTtl.getTag()));

                int curntQty = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) + 1;
                int costPerItem = Integer.valueOf(foodPrice.getText().toString());

                if (qty.getTag() == addBtn.getTag())
                    qty.setText(String.valueOf(curntQty));

                if (priceTtl.getTag() == addBtn.getTag())
                    priceTtl.setText(String.valueOf(costPerItem * curntQty));

                new MenuPage().addItem(costPerItem);

            }
        });

        holder.removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (qty.getText().toString() != "0") {

                    int qtyTtl = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) - 1;
                    qty.setText(String.valueOf(qtyTtl));

                    int costPerItem = Integer.valueOf(foodPrice.getText().toString());
                    int curPrice = Integer.valueOf(priceTtl.getText().toString());

                    priceTtl.setText(String.valueOf(curPrice - costPerItem));

                    new MenuPage().removeItem(costPerItem);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add Item First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    return convertView;
}


private static class ViewHolder {

    private TextView foodItem;
    private TextView foodPrice;
    private ImageView foodType;
    private ImageButton addBtn;
    private ImageButton removeBtn;
    private TextView qty;
    private TextView priceCurnt;


    public ViewHolder(View v) {

        foodItem = v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        foodPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.per_item_cost);
        foodType = v.findViewById(R.id.fdTypeImg);
        addBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.img_add);
        removeBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.img_remove);
        qty = v.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
        priceCurnt = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_cost);
    }
}
```

Comment: You were not giving proper reference that click function is for which button. By changing the give code as I mentioned above your code can differentiate that u pressed button of which specific listview item.Happy coding :)

Comment: I changed little bit the way you are inflating the listView. Try with edited changes. Hope so it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code `addBtn.setOnClickListene`r to and do the same with `removeBtn button.setOnClickListener`

```
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Log.v("btn tag", String.valueOf(addBtn.getTag()));
        Log.v("qty tag", String.valueOf(qty.getTag()));
        Log.v("Price tag", String.valueOf(priceTtl.getTag()));

        int curntQty = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) + 1;
        // update your quantity to data model here
        dataModel.updateQuantiy(curntQty);

        int costPerItem = Integer.valueOf(foodPrice.getText().toString());

        /*if (qty.getTag() == addBtn.getTag())
            qty.setText(String.valueOf(curntQty));*/

        if (priceTtl.getTag() == addBtn.getTag())
            priceTtl.setText(String.valueOf(costPerItem * curntQty));

        new MenuPage().addItem(costPerItem);

        // Notify that the data set change at the position to re-binding layout.
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
});
```

And

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    // Your normal code

    DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);

    holder.foodItem.setTag(position);
    holder.foodItem.setText(dataModel.getItemTitleFinal());

    holder.foodPrice.setTag(position);
    holder.foodPrice.setText(dataModel.getItemPriceFinal());

    holder.foodType.setTag(position);
    holder.foodType.setImageResource(dataModel.getItemImgFinal());

    holder.addBtn.setTag(position);
    holder.removeBtn.setTag(position);
    holder.qty.setTag(position);
    holder.priceCurnt.setTag(position);

   // add your quantity to textview
   holder.qty.setText(dataModel.getQuantity());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Sorry your code is not helpful, it still changes  item 7 value when i change item 0 value

Comment: update your adapter code after changed, please. I will check it out